# Modify Quick-Fix 'Change visibility to default'

Tags: java, eclipse

Assuming the following situation:
I have a *private* field and an inner class referencing or modifying this field. The compiler marks this as a warning, because the field should be *protected* (default visibility). so far so good.

Eclipse is clever enough to provide a quick fix for this case, when I use it, it just removes the *private* modifier.

This removes the warning, but does not match my code style. I'd like it to replace the word *private* with *protected* instead.

Is there a way to modify how the Quickfix behaves?

Example Code for better understanding: foo inside the ActionListener is marked as warning

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test {

    private String foo = "bar";

    public void bla() {

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                foo = "whatev";
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Thanks to Aleks and Thin Pham. I misunderstood the visibility of *default* and *protected*. Still, is there a way to modify the Quickfix?

Comment: Note that "default" visibility and "protected" visibility are not the same thing.  `protected` means that the field is accessible by all descendant classes; default visibility means that the field is accessible by all classes in the same package.

Comment: Default visibility is not protected, in java it should be Package, while in .NET it should be Internal.

Comment: @AleksG thanks, I misunderstood that... still i'd like to modify the quickfix to make the field protected, unless it isn't good practise for something like my sample code (?)

Answer (score 0):

My "style" would be to create some sort of (protected if neccessary) setter for the private field because i try to avoid non-private fields. The problem with non-private fields is that you will have to add a lot of additional code in the base class to catch every possible and invalid change that can come from the descendant classes. If you have a protected/public setter, you can just catch every invalid change in this setter and the rest of the class does not have to worry about it.

In some cases, it makes absolutely sense to create a non-private field, but your code example is usually not one of them (at least for me).

Answer (score -1):

The quick fixes are contributed, like everything else in Eclipse, by a plugin. Most likely one of the JDT plugins. The only thing I think you can really do would be to write your own Quick Fix in your own plugin.